# How to create multiple instances in 1 table? Cannot write into Null rows because it's "Read Only" in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Okay so here is my problem. I'm creating a database for my local soccer team.

In Table_A (**GameInfo**),

I am keeping track of each game with primary key

```
idGameSchedule: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, etc...
```

In Table_B (**Players**),

I am keeping track of each player with primary key:

```
ID: 1, 2, 3, ...
```

The problem is with a specific column in the **Players** Table. Called: *AttendedGame*. When I run this:

```
SELECT * FROM Players, GameInfo;
```

I get the first 3 rows of information for each Player for each game. So the most left column which is *ID* from the **Players**. 
So it looks like:

(SEE ATTACHED PICTURE)
[image: Simplified Query Result]

My Problem:

I cannot write information to the *AttendedGame* column because the only time it has an Instance for each game is when you query both tables. So if were to query just:

```
SELECT * FROM Players;
```

I will only receive 1 unique id for each player. The table won't get an id for each game in the **GameInfo** table. So they player name doesn't repeat. I can't write data to the row for *AttendedGame* because there isn't one row for each game.›

Eventually when there are 4 games there will be 4 id's and when there are 5 games there will be 5 rows with the same id in the **Players** table. So if I wanted to narrow attendance down I can just use a WHERE statement.

All I want to know is did a player show up for the game or did they not show up for the game when I query:

```
SELECT * FROM Players;
```

I am using MySQL Workbench. Is this a foreign key issue?

This is my first question on Stackoverflow so please be nice. Thank you!

Comment: the picture looks like a cartesian product which is what the `from x,y` does

Answer (score 1):

You're getting all those results because you haven't specified any relationship between the tables. So it returns a full cross product between all the rows in both tables.

Your design is not properly normalized. You need a relation table that tracks which games each player has attended, you shouldn't put this information in the `Players` table.

```
CREATE TABLE PlayerAttendedGame (
    player_id INT(11),
    game_id INT(11),
    PRIMARY KEY (player_id, game_id),
    CONSTRAINT player_fk FOREIGN KEY (player_id) REFERENCES Players(ID),
    CONSTRAINT game_fk FOREIGN KEY (game_id) REFERENCES GameInfo(idGameSchedule));
```

You put a row in this table for each game that each player attended.

Then to find which games the players have attended, you join the 3 tables.

```
SELECT p.Name, g.GameDate
FROM Players AS p
JOIN PlayerAttendedGame pg ON p.ID = pg.player_id
JOIN GameData AS g ON pg.game_id = g.idGameSchedule
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Yes I did already think about that option. Create another relational table. I just didn't know if there was an easier way to do it with just 2 tables. Best Regards.